# interactive function command in R

Tags: r, function, interactive

I have question with interactive Rmd, which I am not even sure if it is possible.
So I have made a function that takes 4 inputs in command to run. I am wondering if I can make a program/ line that lets the user input the inputs in the Rmd (html).

for example,
if a line to ran a 'run_function' function is

```
run_function(1,2,"3",4)
```

I wonder if I can configure smt on Rmd to prompt the user to input each variables

```
Enter var 1: x
Enter var 2: y
Enter var 3: "5"
Enter var 4: f

to ran the following command automatically 
-> run_function(x,t,"5",f)
```

Will this be possible? In R, without using python?

I am attaching my function and exp output

```
run_diff<-function(model_in, contr_in,graph_title,txt_title){
  t<-diff(df_filt,model_in,contr_in)
  write.table(t, file = txt_title, row.names = F, sep = "\t", quote = F)
  print(head(t,10))
  DEsites_count<-as.integer(length(which(t$adj.P.Val < 0.05)))
  string<-"Number of Differentially Editing sites are"
  print(paste(string, DEsites_count))
  g<- ggplot(t, aes(x=logFC, y=-log10(P.Value))) + 
    theme_minimal() +geom_jitter(aes(color=AveExpr), alpha=0.3, size = 2)+
    theme(text = element_text(size = 10))+
    ggtitle(graph_title)
  print(g)
}

run_diff(model_2,"contr_1", "Model_2, contr1","model_2_contr_1_toptable.txt")
-> produces a table, a graph, and saves a txt file
```

Comment: Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45888571/knitr-with-user-input . A possibility is using shiny within quarto and giving users the ability to interact with the `html`

Answer (score 0):

Not possible if the command executes in R. Rmd renders static html files.  The options you have are to use JavaScript in the Rmd to do what I think you intend or create a Rshiny markdown app. The later is dependent on the client having R on their machine or the app being hosted on a shinyserver.  It’s important to note the Rmd when knitted executes the R code and translates or captures the outputs in html, JS and CSS.

Comment: no problem, if I answered your question can you mark it as answered?